# CAS: Service Ticket/CAS-Server reply is empty

Tags: c++, rest, cas

I use the RESTful API and when I take the TGT to request an ST at `https://www.mysite.de/cas/v1/tickets/" + tgt` my CAS server throws this:

```
2016-10-12 18:07:39,168 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping] - <No flow mapping found for request with URI '/cas/v1/tickets/TGT-**********************************************6rXJ4WKxmo-cas01.example.org'>
2016-10-12 18:07:39,168 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping] - <No flow mapping found for request with URI '/cas/v1/tickets/TGT-**********************************************6rXJ4WKxmo-cas01.example.org'>
2016-10-12 18:07:39,168 WARN [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] - <No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/cas/v1/tickets/TGT-**********************************************6rXJ4WKxmo-cas01.example.org] in DispatcherServlet with name 'cas'>
```

When I print out my response in my console I just get:

`Service Ticket: 0♠`

The `0♠` is what is in the response that I get by doing this:

```
QByteArray replyData = reply->readAll();
QString serviceTicket = QString::fromAscii(replyData.data());
fprintf(stderr, "Service Ticket: %s\n", QString::fromAscii(replyData.data()));
```

I guess I have a misunderstanding here. I just suppose that the reply is a `QString`or at least will be converted the right way. Is it possible that the reply has a format that simply cannot be converted like that? If yes, what do I need to do?

If this is not the reason and the reply is simply an emptry reply or something, the above mentioned `DEBUG` info might indicate what my problem is.

Do I maybe have to make any other changes to the `web.xml` in order to get REST working here? Everything I did was just from [this source](https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/protocol/REST-Protocol.html).

**EDIT:** Seems like a bug from CAS 4.2.6. I downgraded to 4.2.5 and now I get a NullPointerException on teh CAS Server when i send the encrypted TGT over the RESTful APi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this is a bug from CAS 4.2.6. Go to `WEB-INF\lib\cas-server-webapp-support-4.2.6.jar\META-INF\spring\web-ctx-config.xml` in your war and change this:

```
<bean id="urlPathHelperWeb" class="org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper"
          p:alwaysUseFullPath="true" />
```

to this:

```
<bean id="urlPathHelperWeb" class="org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper"
          p:alwaysUseFullPath="false" />
```